# the inventory (host) list in ansible is in /etc/ansible/; what is reasons to have it in /etc?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am new to `ansible` and work on my setup. I see that the list of hosts is per default in `/etc/anisble/hosts` and changed with root privileges. In tutorials I have seen solutions with the host file in user space.

I would prefer to have all `ansible` setup under my home directory. What is the advantage of putting the hosts file in `/etc` respective the reason that the default location is there?

Thank you for clarification!

Comment: You can put your inventory wherever your want and call it with the `-i` option, e.g. `ansible-playbook -i /path/to/my/inventory ...` You can set the default inventory in `ansible.cfg`, globally and/or at project level.

Comment: I saw this in the tutorials I followed. My questin is only:  why did the developers put it in /etc/ and have it own by root? I assume they had a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security perspective, putting it in the /etc directory is the safest initial option for a few reasons.

If Ansible defaulted to using an inventory file in the 'current directory' the playbook is executed in, then it would be easy for a bad actor to place an inventory file in other commonly used directories that are accessed by multiple people (such as /tmp, /var/tmp, etc). If they succeeded in getting someone to execute a playbook in that directory, it could perform additional actions the user didn't expect.

If Ansible default to using an inventory file in your home directory, this could open up that user to exploits by someone sending them a malicious email attachment or other method to write a file in their home directory that they weren't expecting.

Comment: Thank you - this was the information I was hoping for. I see some additional protection, but it seems small: using ansible a maliciou user can execute (nearly) any code on any host - or do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: If you've got wide-open permissions on the account you are using with Ansible (i.e. you're connecting with "root" and a password), then yes the machines that you connect into are at the mercy of the user and their Ansible playbook.

There are lots of discussions of best practices - generally have Ansible connect in as a non-root user using an SSH key, and require that account to use sudo/su (e.g. the "become:"/"become_user:" directives in Ansible).

Comment: ... which  has me then enter the sudo password or store it somewhere (perhaps on my local keyring).  I will likely have a special account which has sudo without password and login with a key (not password).  --  I will search for the 'best practice' discussion! Thank you, you have been very helpful with your clarifications.